# MySql (MariaDB 10.4.13) "LOCK TABLES 'reqphones' WRITE" syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am using WAMP with PHP 7+ and MariaDB 10.4.13.

When I try to do:

```
LOCK TABLES 'reqphones' WRITE
```

in a server PHP script.

I get a syntax error near "  'reqphones' WRITE  ".

I also tried this in phpMyAdmin and several online SQL syntax validators and get the same syntax error.

I have also tried with out the single quotes around the table name with the same result.

I have checked my userid privileges and I have all privileges.

Clearly I am missing something, so any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Don't use single quotes around table names.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this.

In 60 years doing this computer stuff, one thing that has really annoyed me is when a problem just seems to go away.

That just happened!

All I did was hibernate my system last night and resume it this morning and every thing worked.

Infernal machines!

Jim